# Do I need to be a Paypal Certified Dev to implement Paypal on my website?

Tags: paypal

I'm actually working for a client. I've succesfully implemented paypal pro on the website and everything is working fine, I believe I followed their process and guidelines to make it work the way they meant.

Thus, I've been reading [this webpage](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/going-live-with-your-application#register) to turn the website in procuduction, and [somewhere in the policies and guidelines](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-application-policies-and-guidelines) , they say (and it is rule nb 1 !):

> To make API calls to the PayPal production servers, you must be a
>   registered PayPal Developer and have a PayPal Premier or Business
>   Account in good standing.

So ... does that mean that I can't turn it in prod by myself ? I'm not a certified Paypal neither a registered paypal dev.

Please Advice :)
Thanks

Comment: I'd also like to know the answer to this. During my many, many attempts at trying to implement paypal payments, they have all failed, even though some experts have said my code is fine and could not explain why it wouldn't work - and after seeing this question, I am now wondering if I need to be a certified developer. I find it hard to believe, but would be good to know.

Comment: let me know if my answer solve your interrogation

Comment: @Joey "We know where the party is and we will point the cops your way." kind of deal. It's the same with Google. A lot of their API you need to have a developer key that the application will check against a database I suppose. It's like a track record if you did something malicious or bad. Like make a troyan or whatever, they can just lock all applications with your key. I think it's the same deal. Security.

Comment: Ohhh, ok. I have a developer account and sandbox account with a vverified bank account too. Along with the API Key and Signature and everything. I thought that maybe that was different from a "certified" developer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I 've found out that you simply need to register as a Paypal Developer. It takes a few minutes and its free. You need to sign up with your regular paypal account and then turn it into a developer one( just like Facebook did with their API).

Just click on sign up with paypal and follow the instructions:
https://developer.paypal.com/

I made it that way a few months ago.
Hope that help !

Comment: Thanks Miles. It helped. Now I need to figure out why it won't work :P DO they require that your website is using HTTPS? I've seen HTTPS mentioned but haven't seen anything that says it's a requirement (it is something that I will be adding though)

Comment: yes it is required, you need an ssl certificate to do real life transactions ( dunno if it is necessary for sandbox though)

Comment: I remember at the beginning nothing was lcear to me, but this thread was VERY usefull to me: http://www.angelleye.com/download-codeigniter-php-library-for-paypal-payments-pro/
Don't know if you're using Codeigniter but you might find good info. And, this guys is a certified Paypal dev who will help you personally if you set up a x$ skype appointment with him.
You can still use the comments to ask a question if it is general (otherwise, not sure he will answer since you're not using his library)